# Dynamic casting objects from object array to the respective classes available in an enumeration

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream, dynamic-cast

```
public class A {
     private String property;
     public String getProperty() {
          return property;
     }
}
public class B {
     private String property;
     public String getProperty() {
          return property;
     }
}
```

similarly Classes C and D are defined.(Omitting the other logic and complexity)

Then created an enumeration of these class names.[simple class name or canonical class name I can add without a problem]

```
public enum ClassNameEnum{ A, B, C, D }
```

In another class I have an Object array which contain instances of any of the classes in enumeration.

**My Objective:**
Get each element in object array, cast them to one of the classe names in myEnum and perform a method invocation.

What I have done so far.
(1) loop through object array and have if else ladder to check instanceof. If matching, cast and do operation [working but ugly]

(2) Improvement:

```
public class ImplClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Object> objectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        objectList.add(new B());
        objectList.add(new D());
        objectList.add(new A());

        for (Object object : objectList) {
            Arrays.asList(ClassNameEnum.values()).stream()
            .filter(e -> obj instanceof e)   // Error here: e cannot be resolved to a type
            .map(e -> (e)obj)
            .map("Call getProperty() on the casted object and return the string"); // This is what I want to do
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your classes related in some way? Do they have some common behavior that can be put in a parent class?

Comment: They are unrelated. Auto generated class from XSD.

Comment: so you have a List of some objects, where potentially some of them are enum instances - so you want to filter only enum instances and call a method on them? is it a common method for all of them?

Comment: @Eugene, he might have stored the qualified class name in the `Enum`, eventually to cast them at run time.

Comment: @mark42inbound may be, but this is very unclear at this point

Comment: @Eugene, I had a similar scenario, but they were inherited from a parent class. So the solution was pretty much simple.

Comment: @Eugene 
Exactly but one change, not some of them but all of them will be instances of one of the enumeration element

Comment: ... and they all have the same method to be called? this makes little sense. why not simply `List<Object> test = List.of(myEnum.A, myEnum.B);

        test.stream()
                .map(x -> (myEnum)x)
                .map(x -> x.yourMethod)`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ravindra,

Stream.of(MyEnum.values()).filter(e -> e instanceof MyEnum).map(e -> (MyEnum) e);


 This has no compilation issue. But I can't call e.getXX() on casted object.

Info : e.getXX() returns a String

Comment: what does return type of `getXX` has to do with on whom you are calling it?

Comment: @Eugene 
... Yes it is a common method in all classes. But to call this method, the object first need to be cast of it's own clasd and then can invoke method. As in your last solution, Object array is not used. Even if used, class cast exception will be thrown unless we use filter.

Comment: I hope someone will make sense out of this mess, because I don't understand anything. may be provide the real code *before* steam solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of enum you can store the classes into a structure like:

```
class ClassInfo<T> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Function<T, String> function;

    // all args constructor here

    String castAndApply(Object obj) {
        return function.apply(clazz.cast(obj));
    }
}
```

then create a map, for example:

```
Map<Class, ClassInfo> classInfos = Map.of(
  A.class, new ClassInfo<>(A.class, A::getA),
  B.class, new ClassInfo<>(B.class, B::getB),
  C.class, new ClassInfo<>(C.class, C::getProperty)
);
```

and below is the usage:

```
objectList.stream()
        .filter(obj -> classInfos.containsKey(obj.getClass()))
        .map(obj -> classInfos.get(obj.getClass()).castAndApply(obj))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: First of all Thanks to @Adrian, @Eugene.  @Adrian's solution is what exactly I needed. It works perfectly. Only change is I had instance method hence I used `object::methodName` syntax

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to invoke a common method from all your objects, it makes sense to create an interface here.

```
public interface Property {
   String getProperty();
}
```

And in your class:

```
public class A implement Property {
   private String property;

   @Override
   public String getProperty() {
          return property;
   }
}
```

Try to store your object by its interface reference:

```
List<Property> objectList = new ArrayList<>();
objectList.add(new A());
objectList.add(new B());
...
```

And finally:

```
objectList.forEach(o -> System.out.println(o.getProperty()));
```

Comment: I tried the most approriate answer by @Adrian and it worked. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: That method is just a workaround. The root of problem is inheritance. After all, it's up to you. Cheer!